# Flutter TextField with emoji suggestions

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to configure a TextField (Flutter 3.13.2) so that when typing a couple of letters, it gives emoji suggestions, but cannot find a way.

In iOS on my iPhone, I can see all those suggestions in basically almost every app. For example:

- Hi ->
- Ok ->  ✅
- Haha ->

I can see the exactly same suggestions on my Mac keyboard right now as I am typing.
Currently I have this below, but I get only word suggestions:

```
      TextField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
        enableSuggestions: true,
        autocorrect: true,
        textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences
      )
```

PS: It works on iOS Simulators, but not on actual devices.